# Why modal dialog does opened with data-bs-target swttcher?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I resume working in laravel site with laravel, tailwindcss, alpinejs and found that Modal dialog does not working (I am sure it was working ok).

I have in blade.php file :

```html
    <button type="button" class="listing_btn_filters" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#showFiltersModal" x-show="isPageInitialized && !isProcessing">
        Filter
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade fixed top-0 left-0 hidden w-full h-full outline-none overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto"
         id="showFiltersModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="showFiltersModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable relative w-auto pointer-events-none">
            <div
                class="modal-content shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full pointer-events-auto
                bg-white bg-clip-padding rounded-md outline-none text-current border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg">
                <div
                    class="modal-header flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-between p-4 border-b border-gray-200 rounded-t-md">
                    <h5 class="text-xl font-medium leading-normal text-gray-800" id="showFiltersModalLabel">
                        Products filter
                    </h5>
```

"showFiltersModal" (it is unique ID on whole page) - is key by which modal must be toggled - but clicking on this button nothing happens

if to remove " hidden " in line

```
<div class="modal fade fixed top-0 left-0 hidden w-full h-full outline-none overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto"
```

then modal is always shown. But this property is not switched by clicking on "Filter" button with property and I can not understand why?

Any ideas ?

I run

```
 npm run dev
```

without errors

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.3.9",
```

...

```
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
"alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
"laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.19",
"postcss": "^8.4.6",
"tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
"vite": "^3.0.0"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you are using Tailwind CSS but the problem seems relative to Bootstrap